# Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a function called `setScore( )` in my **APP** component which is passed down as props to my **Popup** Component. I want to call the `UpdateScore( )` function based on a condition in my Popup Component. However, I also want to call the `setScore( )` method based on a condition but it gives me the error listed above.

```
const Popup = ({user,correctLetters,wrongLetters,setPlayable,selectedWord, playAgain, currentQuestion, words, score, setScore, quitGame}) => {

    function UpdateScore() {

            if(!check){
                check = true;    
                setScore(score => (score + 1));               
            }    
    };

    if ((checkWin(correctLetters,wrongLetters,selectedWord) === 'win') && (currentQuestion < words.length -1)){
        UpdateScore();
    } 
    else if((checkWin(correctLetters,wrongLetters,selectedWord) === 'win') && (currentQuestion === words.length -1 )){
        UpdateScore();
    }
```

This isn't the complete code but the main issue is with the `setState( )` call. I've looked at other posts and they resolved it by wrapping the `setState` method in a `useEffect` but then it gives me another *error* :

> Cannot Conditionally render useEffects.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: You are calling `setScore` in your `Popup` render. You can't do that. If you need to update your state when a variable changes use the `useEffect` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the following works:

```
const isWin =
  checkWin(correctLetters, wrongLetters, selectedWord) ===
    'win' &&
  currentQuestion <= words.length &&
  !check;
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (isWin) {
    check = true;
    setScore((score) => score + 1);
  }
}, [isWin, setScore]);
```

I do see a problem with `check` and have a feeling it should be in a useRef.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved it! I needed to render after check win was satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling a `UpdateScore` (that calls `setScore`) in component's body and this is not how React works. If you want to execute `if...else if` at `Popup` first render, use an `useEffect` hook in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if ((checkWin(correctLetters,wrongLetters,selectedWord) === 'win') && (currentQuestion < words.length -1)){
        UpdateScore();
    } 
    else if((checkWin(correctLetters,wrongLetters,selectedWord) === 'win') && (currentQuestion === words.length -1 )){
        UpdateScore();
    }
}, [correctLetters, wrongLetters, selectedWord, currentQuestion, UpdateScore]);
```

Actually, this `useEffect` will be triggered every time one of `correctLetters, wrongLetters, selectedWord, currentQuestion, UpdateScore` changes his value (but you need these as dependencies otherwise you will get a warning on "missing dependencies").

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. its solved :)

Comment: @HaroonOmer No problem. Have a nice coding =)